# ¿Cómo ejecutar una consulta guardada en una variable en un procedimiento de mysql?

Tags: mysql, string, sql

El problema viene dado al realizar el insert, ya que inserta un String de la consulta en la tabla. Y lo que yo quiero es que haga el insert del valor de la consulta. En el caso que tenga la query escrita sin estar en una variable funciona perfectamente.
Pero claro no es una solución porque necesito recorrer la tabla y ejecutar cada consulta que se encuentra en cada fila y no tener un procedimiento con todas las consultas escritas a mano.

La solución es obtener la tabla con el resultado de las consultas realizadas de otra tabla.
No se si me he explicado muy bien...

```
FETCH cursor_sel_idIndicador INTO consulta_id,consulta_query;
    -- Replace de las fechas para realizar las consultas
    set consulta_new_fecha = (REPLACE(REPLACE(consulta_query,'dateStart',dateStart),'dateEnd',dateEnd));        

            IF findelbucle = 1 THEN
            LEAVE bucle;
            END IF;

    INSERT INTO list_value (Fecha, Valor, IdIndicator) VALUES(dateStart,consulta_new,consulta_id);
```

Comment: preferiria crear una clase y agregar una funcion que realice este trabajo y que pueda darle mantenimiento en codigo y no estar toqueteando la base de datos...

Comment: lo que no veo es de la variable... y como se supone que debe interpretar que es una variable algo como :   DECLARE newname VARCHAR(5);
  DECLARE xid INT; donde guardaras la variable que usaras luego.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Las variables se encuentran declaradas , lo único que no las puse al pegar el código. De todas formas tal vez haga lo que dijiste le doy soporte desde el código externo de la BD

Comment: cuando subas una ejemplo subelo completo... no podemos adivinar codigo o asumir, ya que para el programador lo que hace falta es siempre un error de sintaxis.